# How to use Boost library in QT creator on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: c++, qt, ubuntu, boost

I want to use the C++ Boost library in the QT creator on Ubuntu 14.04, after trying many methods, I still get errors.

I installed the Boost library using:

```
sudo apt-get install libboost-all-dev
```

The Boost library is installed in the directory:

```
/usr/include/boost
```

Here is my main.cpp

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include<iostream>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/steady_timer.hpp>

using namespace std;


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

    boost::asio::steady_timer timer_;
    timer_.expires_from_now(1000);


    return a.exec();
}
```

Any my .pro file:

```
QT += core
QT -= gui

CONFIG += c++11

TARGET = test_boost_lib_in_QT
CONFIG += console
CONFIG -= app_bundle

TEMPLATE = app

SOURCES += main.cpp

INCLUDEPATH += /usr/include/boost

LIBS += -L/usr/include/boost -lboost_system
LIBS += -L/usr/include/boost  -lboost_chrono
LIBS += -L/usr/include/boost  -lboost_thread
LIBS += -L/usr/include/boost  -lboost_timer
```

The compiling errors are: (I compiled directly from QT using "ctrl+B")

```
/home/ndn-experiment/Desktop/test_boost_lib_in_QT/main.cpp:13: error: no matching function for call to 'boost::asio::basic_waitable_timer<std::chrono::_V2::steady_clock>::basic_waitable_timer()'
 boost::asio::steady_timer timer_;
                           ^

/home/ndn-experiment/Desktop/test_boost_lib_in_QT/main.cpp:14: error: no matching function for call to 'boost::asio::basic_waitable_timer<std::chrono::_V2::steady_clock>::expires_from_now(int)'
 timer_.expires_from_now(1000);
                             ^
```

What should I do?

Comment: first - asio requires an io_service. there is no default constructor for steady_timer. second - expires_from_now requires a duration as parameter. there is no overload for an int parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After going through so many posts on the Internet and so many errors I encountered, I finally make my program run. 
Hereby I want to answer my own question, emphasizing two points:

1. another way of creating an object of a class whose constructor takes more than 1 arguments
2. the right way to use `boost::asio::steady_timer`

My main.cpp

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/steady_timer.hpp>
#include <chrono>
#include <boost/chrono.hpp>

using namespace std;

typedef boost::asio::steady_timer timer_type;

class timer_expire{

public:

    timer_expire(boost::asio::io_service& io):timer_(io){}

    void timer_expires(int n_milliseconds) {

        timer_.expires_from_now(boost::chrono::milliseconds(n_milliseconds));

        //need timer_.async_wait() here

    }

private:
    timer_type timer_;
};



int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

    boost::asio::io_service io;

    timer_expire timer_expire_(io);
    timer_expire_.timer_expires(10000);

    return a.exec();
}
```

My .pro file (please note the `QMAKE_CXXFLAGS`)

```
QT += core
QT -= gui

CONFIG += c++11

TARGET = test_boost_lib_in_QT
CONFIG += console
CONFIG -= app_bundle

TEMPLATE = app

SOURCES += main.cpp

CONFIG += c++11

QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -std=c++11

INCLUDEPATH += /usr/include/boost

QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -DBOOST_ASIO_DISABLE_STD_CHRONO
LIBS += -L/usr/include/boost -lboost_system -lboost_chrono -lboost_thread -lboost_timer
```

My `g++` version is 4.8.4

Note that there is another way to the `boost::asio::steady_timer` by setting the `QMAKE_CXXFLAGS` to `-DBOOST_ASIO_HAS_STD_CHRONO`, please refer to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27552028/who-is-failing-boost-clang-or-gcc-issue-with-stdchrono-used-with-boostas).

Also take a look at [Chrono](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/doc/html/boost_asio/overview/cpp2011/chrono.html).

Comment: your wrapper class is bad as it does hide the type of the duration. the original interface you could pass hours, seconds and so on. your interface does not give any hint it requires a number of miliseconds, while the original one was type-safe.

Comment: @stefan just a toy class to show how to compile the **boost::asio::steady_timer** successfully.

Answer (score 2):

The first one is because you need to pass `io_service` to the constructor:

```
boost::asio::io_service io;
boost::asio::steady_timer timer(io);
```

The second one is because `expires_from_now` doesn't take `int`, it requires a `duration` argument:

```
timer.expires_from_now(boost::posix_time::seconds(5));
```

It's also a good general idea to check the [documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/steady_timer.html), it has usage examples.